# (ADS5295) 12bit ADC with 14x serialization

Tags: adc, texas-instruments

I am using 12bit ADC, Texas Instruments ADS5295.

In manual of ADS5295, it says ADS5295 supports 14x and 16x serialization factor.

The resolution of ADS5295 is 12bit.

If I set 14x serialization factor, is output data  composed of 12 valid bit and 2 dummy bit ?

At page 79, it says 'When digital signal processing functions are used, the 14x and 16x serialization modes can also be used.'

- What kind of digital filter do I need to using 14x serialization with ADS5295?
- Which register do I have to set?

Answer (score 1):

The ADC includes a built-in decimation filter block. If you turn this on, the filter will trade sample rate for resolution (by averaging across multiple samples), so the effective output of the ADC will be greater than the native 12-bits. Hence why the option is provided to read data from the chip at a higher resolution.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Your reply was very helpful to me.!